# como comparo una lista/tupla que tienen la misma longitud y mismos valores pero en distinto orden para que esta me de True

Tags: python, lista, clase, tuplas

estoy trabajando con clases y necesito comparar los lados de 2 triangulos y que devuelva True si los valores son iguales a pesar de que esten en distinto orden, por ejemplo (4,5,3) == (3,4,5) True

```
# Definir la clase Triangulo
class Triangulo:
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        assert type(a)==type(b)==type(c)!=float, "los valores de los atributos deben ser numeros flotantes"
        assert a+b>c and a+c>b and b+c>a, "la suma de dos de sus lados debe ser mayor que el lado restante (Por teorema de desigualdad del triangulo)"
        self.__a = a
        self.__b = b
        self.__c = c

    def son_iguales(self ,otro):
        if ((self.__a,self.__b,self.__c) == (otro.self.__a, otro.self.__a, otro.self.__a)):
            return True
```

Comment: Intenta Cambiar tu if en tu método **son_iguales** y coloca así: **if set((self.__a, self.__b, self.__c)) == set((otro.__a, otro.__b, otro.__c)):** y nos comentas

Comment: Me olvide por completo del método set que los convierte a conjunto y en los conjuntos no importa el orden, gracias! sirvio

quedo asi:

def son_iguales(self ,otro):
        r = False
        if set((self.__a,self.__b,self.__c)) == set((otro.__a, otro.__b, otro.__c)):
            r = True
        return r

Comment: Perfecto, saludos

Comment: No es tan perfecto: (1,1,2) != (1,2,2)

Answer (score 2):

el código funcionó trabajando con conjuntos en donde no importa el orden:

```
def son_iguales(self ,otro):
        r = False
        if set((self.__a,self.__b,self.__c)) == set((otro.__a, otro.__b, otro.__c)):
            r = True
        return r
```

Comment: No hace falta la variable auxiliar ni el `if`, puedes retornar directamente el valor de la comparación.

Comment: Tu código no funcionará. Los objetos `set` en Python no admiten repeticiones. Por lo tanto `set(1,1,2) == set(2,2,1)`, lo cual no es el resulado que esperas.

Comment: no me deja ingresar esos valores por que no cumplen con el teorema de desigualdad del triangulo, ¿Podrías darme otro ejemplo de porque no funcionaria mi código?.

Comment: No puedo. Es fácil demostrar que es imposible construir dos ternas de números positivos que cumplan la desigualdad triangular de la forma `(a, a, b)` y `(b, b, a)`. `set` bajo la hipótesis de desigualdad triangular funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer una lista con los lados de cada uno, ordenarlas y luego compararlas. Si las listas son iguales, los triángulos son iguales, por ejemplo:

```
def son_iguales(self ,otro):
    assert type(otro) == Triangulo, "El otro objeto a comparar en son_iguales debe ser un triángulo"
    mislados = sorted([self.__a, self.__b, self.__c])
    ladosotro = sorted([otro.__a, otro.__b, otro.__c])
    return mislados == ladosotro
```

Esta prueba:

```
a = Triangulo(4,5,3)
b = Triangulo(3,4,5)

if (a.son_iguales(b)):
    print("son iguales")
else:
    print("no son iguales")
```

Imprimiría *son iguales*.

Una vez has comprendido los pasos, el método podría simplificarse a:

```
def son_iguales(self ,otro):
    return sorted([self.__a, self.__b, self.__c]) == sorted([otro.__a, otro.__b, otro.__c])
```

**Edición**: La versión original de esta respuesta tenía un error, gracias a Chema por apuntarlo.

Comment: Ojo con el método `.sort()`. Ordena la lista, pero retorna `None`. Usa mejor la función `sorted()`.

Comment: Gracias, Chema, justo estaba cayendo en la cuenta de ese error al hacer una prueba adicional para _simplificar_ el código. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

podrias intentar hacer lo siguiente:

```
T_Aux2 = [otro.self__a,otro.self__b,otro.self__c]
T_Aux = [self__a,self__b,self__c]
BolR = False

Con = 0
i = 0

while len(T_Aux) != 0 :
    a = T_Aux[0]
    x = 0
    
    while x <   len(T_Aux2):
        b = T_Aux2[x]
        if a == b:
            T_Aux2.remove(b)
            Con += 1
            break
        x += 1
    T_Aux.remove(a)

if(Con == 3):
    BolR = True

return BolR
```

Lo que hace esto hacer unas  listas auxiliares, itera en ambas para encontrar similitudes, una vez encuentra una la elimina de las tuplas para asegurarse de no errores futuros, al terminar la iteracion tienes la cantidad de similitudes, si es igual a 3 cambia el valor de BolR a True, si no se queda en False y el final se retorna, espero te funcione !, te mostrare el codigo con un ejemplo con numeros.

```
T_Aux2 = [2,2,5]
T_Aux = [1,5,2]
BolR = False

Con = 0
i = 0

while len(T_Aux) != 0 :
    a = T_Aux[0]
    x = 0
    
    while x <   len(T_Aux2):
        b = T_Aux2[x]
        if a == b:
            T_Aux2.remove(b)
            Con += 1
            break
        x += 1
    T_Aux.remove(a)

if(Con == 3):
    BolR = True

print(BolR)
```

Answer (score 1):

El error en tu lógica fue comparar `self.__a, self.__b, self.__c` con `otro.self.__a, otro.self.__a, otro.self.__a`.

El error en el resultado ocurrió porque repetiste `otro.self.__a`.
*otro.self.__a, otro.self.__a, otro.self.__a*.

La lógica correcta es verificar si los lados son iguales y si están en el orden correcto. Una forma simplificada es ordenar los valores de los triángulos y luego hacer la comparación.

Una respuesta simple:

```
sorted([self.__a, self.__b, self.__c])
```

e

```
sorted([otro.__a, otro.__b, otro.__c])
```

Al usar el [**sorted**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html), se ordenarán los valores en orden creciente del triángulo, creando una lista.
Entonces compara si los valores de la lista son iguales y devuelve True si los triángulos son iguales.

```
def son_iguales(self, otro):
    return sorted([self.__a, self.__b, self.__c]) == sorted([otro.__a, otro.__b, otro.__c])
```